# Unable to retrieve span class and data

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to get text from a span class but unable to get it.

```
<span class="one">
First Text
</span>

<span class="two">
Second Text
</span>
```

And finding it by using JAVA code

```
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.className("one"));
String expMsg = element.getText();
```

But what is actually happening, I am able to retrieve the text but not the span whose class name is one but whose class name is two.

Comment: Try using the xpath instead of class names.

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha - tried but the result was same.

Comment: if you are using firepath, simply select css and evaluate .one  it will helps you

Comment: Already tried not working murali

Answer (score 0):

Try below XPath:-

```
//span[@class='one']/text()
```

Use below code :-

```
String expMsg = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[@class='one']/text()")).getText();
```

Hope it will help you :)